# Require Jenkins Pipeline script for Maven build and Maven Test from Pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I am new to Jenkins and I have created the Maven+TestNG project in eclipse I which I have executed the sample test case to print hello world from POM.xml,which is running fine. I have pushed the project in GIT as well Now I need to execute this from Jenkins using Pipeline script for CI/CD.

I have created below Pipleline script in Jenkins pipeline tab but I am getting error which executing the script. Can you please guide me or provide me the tutorial link where I can get Jenkins pipeline example.

The script is as follow:

```
node {
 def mvnHome
 stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
  // Get some code from a GitHub repository
   git 'https://github.com/jitsolution19/RestAssured_Framework.git'
  // Get the Maven tool.
  // ** NOTE: This 'M3' Maven tool must be configured
  // **       in the global configuration.           
   mvnHome = tool 'Maven'
 }
 stage('Build') {
  // Run the maven build
  if (isUnix()) {
     sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package"
  } else {
     bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package/)
  }
}
stage('Test')   {
   //Perform test
   echo 'Execute the script'
    if (isUnix()) {
      sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore test"
  } else {
     bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore test/)
  }

 }
 stage('Results') {
  junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
  archive 'target/*.jar'
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your error? Please edit the question to add the error message (stack trace etc.)

Comment: Not the error you are searching for, but doing "mvn package" already includes the "mvn test" so you are doing some things twice. Read about the maven lifecycle.